# 1st Day of Current Year in Date Range Criteria in PS Query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I know how to select the first day of the first month of the current year in a number of different formats. The following works fine:  `'01-JAN-' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),'YYYY')`.

However, I need to use January 1, of the current year in a date range criteria in a YTD PSoft Query:

```
WHERE A.effdt BETWEEN (January 1, Current_Year) AND SYSDATE.
```

When I use the expression `'01-JAN-' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),'YYYY')` in the criteria, I get the following error:

```
A SQL error occurred. Please consult your system log for details.
Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=1858, Message=ORA-01858:
a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected (50,380)`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  When asking questions about SQL, especially in the area of date/time handling, it is important to identify the DBMS you are using.  Since there's an ORA in the error, you are presumably using Oracle.  You may need to parenthesize the concatenation expression, or you may need to convert the result to a date value (maybe TO_DATE again?).

Comment: There are two solutions to your question, depending on the input. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should **NEVER** compare `LITERAL` with `DATE`. Since, Oracle will do an `IMPLICIT` conversion. And, sooner or later, it would become a performance issue.

Explicitly convert the literal to date using `TO_DATE`.

For example,

Depending on the date value input method,

**1. If you are passing the literal via some program**

`BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') and SYSDATE`

**2. If you already have the date value in table, then use `TRUNC`**

`BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') and SYSDATE`